# Transpose non Numeric column in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, transpose

I have a data set that looks like the following: 
Index, Key, Value

```
1, Description, Apple
2, Type, Orange
3, Desciption, Apple
4, Type, Pickle
5, Type, Orange
```

I know this can be done if Value is numeric with this:

```
select Index,
max(Case when key = 'Description' then Value else null end)
max(case when key = 'type' the value else null end)
from table
group by Index
```

But given my value column is a string this will not work for my use case. Keep in mind this Redshift so it does not have all the postgres functions. 
Sample Desired output:

```
Index, Description,type
1, Apple, Orange
2, Apple, Pickle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output does not make sense, because there is only one input row per `Index` value. As a result, there is no ability to group the rows into a combined value.

If, instead, your input data was:

```
1, Description, Apple
1, Type, Delicious
2, Description, Banana
2, Type, Big
3, Description, Pineapple
3, Type, Prickly
```

Then you could use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
  index,
  MAX(CASE WHEN description = 'Description' THEN type END) as description,
  MAX(CASE WHEN description = 'Type' THEN type END) as type
FROM food
GROUP BY index
```

The output would be:

```
1   Apple      Delicious
2   Banana     Big
3   Pineapple  Prickly
```